# Which redux-saga effect to use with AMD require

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I want to load a json file in my `redux-saga` and the call looks like this:

```
require("data.json", (data) => {
})
```

I want to use the resulting `data` in a saga to `put` it into the store via an `action`.

Which effect can I use to `wait` for the `require` call to return a resul?
Somehing like this pseudo code:

`const data = yield call(require("data.json"))`

I could use a promise like this:

```
const data = yield call(new Promise((c,e) => {
  require("data.json", c, e)
})
```

But is there a more elegant way?

Comment: If requiring the same file, why can't you load it once and then use in the saga? [`cps`](http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/api/index.html#cpsfn-args) effect could be approximately what you're looking for, but the callback needs to be Node-style (i.e. accept `(error, data)`)

Comment: because I do not want to load it on app start, but only a couple of secs after app start.